# Visual Studio 2017: Create project template > use it > all references broken?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-project

I have three projects(main project, integration test project, unit test project) that are located in a solution A. I want to use them in solution B now. So I read that creating a project template is the cleanest way to do it. So I created project templates for each project and added new projects based on these template in solution B.

The main project works flawlessly, while the references on the unit test and integration test projects are all broken (yellow triangle).

How can I repair them? They have references to the main project and nuget packages.

Comment: Open your `.csproj`, check the HintPaths. Probably a `..\ ` too many.

Answer (score -1):

For **nuget packages** install required packages once again in solution B by selecting respective projects (From nuget package manager).
For **other references** remove all references with yellow triangle. Add them once again one by one.

Comment: That is [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). The problem has an underlying cause. Your proposed solution does not address that.